# How to create a sticky scroll animation navigation bar that is after the full screen carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience

I tried making it with the bootstrap affix but it didn't work for me.
How can I make the sticky navigation bar using JavaScript and the scroll animation using CSS transition or JavaScript?

The data-spy="affix" data-offset-top=""630"> is from bootstrap.

```html
<div class="topnavhome">
  <nav class="navbar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="630">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="logo-wrapper">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="N logo" /></a>
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <div class="social-link">
            <span><i class="fa fa-phone phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 000 000 000000</span>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
              <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="supplements.html">Supplements</a></li>
              <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code. Also the question is not clear enough, try explaining better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: please provide reference; or JSFiddle - 
(sticky-navigation bars are usually with reference to `css` position: fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the navigation bar is sticky after you scroll over the fullscreen carousel. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

To do that, you can use `scroll` event of the `window` element and check when the `offset().top` is higher than the screen height then only at that point, the sticky class or whatever you use to make the navbar sticky will be triggered.